# NLog archiving to same filename

Tags: nlog

I'm interested to know if it's possible to use NLog in the following way.
I'm logging to a FileTarget with the fileName property set to

```
${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}_${date:format=HH\_mm\_ss:cached=true}.log
```

This means that NLog creates a logfile with a name based on when the program was launched. I would like NLog to make a new logfile whenever it will exceed a certain file size. However, I would like the new logfile to be named with the same fileName property.

An example-

NLog writes to 2017-12-31_10_30_00.log, the logfile exceeds the stipulated file size, NLog starts writing to 2017-12-31_11_00_00.log because it's now 11AM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this layoutrenderer instead:

```
${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}_${processinfo:StartTime:format==HH\_mm\_ss}.log
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessInfo-Layout-Renderer