# Nlog Create unique log file for every application startup

Tags: nlog

I would like to create a single log file for entire application.
The log file name convection should includes date and time like this: MyLog_31122022_0915.log

Right now each class creates a new instance meaning a new log file.
If I change the log file name convention, removing date and time, I get a single file, the problem is the the same file is used for each new run of the application.

How can it be done?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47802594/193178 - Ex. `fileName="MyLog_${processinfo:StartTime:format=ddMMyyyy_HHmm:cached=true}.log"`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277631/193178  - Ex. `fileName="MyLog_${processinfo:StartTime:format=ddMMyyyy_HHmm:cached=true}.log"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [${processinfo}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessInfo-Layout-Renderer) to log process-starttime:

```xml
fileName="MyLog_${processinfo:StartTime:format=ddMMyyyy_HHmm:cached=true}.log"
```

You can adjust the DateTime-format to include seconds / milliseconds to make it more unique. Or you can include [${processid}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessId-Layout-Renderer):

```xml
fileName="MyLog_${processinfo:StartTime:format=ddMMyyyy_HHmmss:cached=true}_${processid}.log"
```